"DoCmd.PrintOut" and "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint" Raising Error 2046 in VBA/Access 365
on the Report_Open event, I do the printer settings without any error, as follows:
Dim impressora As Printer

If (nomeImpressora & "" <> "") Then
    Set Application.Printer = Application.Printers(nomeImpressora)
    Set impressora = Application.Printer

    relatorio.Printer.ColorMode = acPRCMColor
    relatorio.Printer.PaperSize = acPRPSA4
    relatorio.Printer.Orientation = acPRORPortrait
    relatorio.Printer.Duplex = acPRDPSimplex
    
    ConfigImpressora = True
End If

on the Report_KeyDown event, I catch the F1 key press in order to run the print command, as follows:
Private Sub Report_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    On Error GoTo TratarErro
    
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyEscape
            DoCmd.Close acReport, Me.Name
'        Case vbKeyF1
'            Me.imgInstrucoesTeclas.Visible = False
'            DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "rptPermissoes"
'            DoCmd.PrintOut acPrintAll
'            DoCmd.Close acReport, Me.Name
        Case vbKeyF1
            Me.imgInstrucoesTeclas.Visible = False
            DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, "rptPermissoes"
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint
            'DoCmd.Close acReport, Me.Name
    End Select
    
Sair:
    Exit Sub
TratarErro:
    If (Err.Number = 2585) Then
        PostMessage Me.hWnd, WM_CLOSE, CLng(0), CLng(0)
    End If
    GoTo Sair
End Sub

both DoCmd.PrintOut acPrintAll and DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint are raising Error 2046, as you can see on the picture.

PS 1: this is one of the messages for error 2046: "The command or action 'OutputTo' isn't available now". despite the translation for the word "Imprimir" is Print. the line that triggers error is DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint (or DoCmd.PrintOut acPrintAll).
PS 2: I disabled all the printer settins code as you said and tried to print using DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint, unsuccessfully. otherwise, when I printed using Ctrl+P it worked. the same dialog window opens in both cases. I just press OK button without making any selection on it. I had an idea of opening the dialog window via SendKeys "^p", it doesn't work. it opens a Microsoft support webpage.
Solution: I changed the print key to F2. now, I'm opening the dialog window with SendKeys "^p". right after I use SendKeys "{ENTER}" to confirm. it's working fine. thanks for the help of everyone, specially to @June7.

Nothing new in this duplicate question (previous has been deleted). I tried simple procedure with the 2 DoCmd lines. Printer dialog opens and when I press OK I get error 2585 "This action can't be carried out while processing a form or report event." I am using HP Pavilion laptop and pressing F1 opens Help window no matter what the code does. I don't see a solution for this.

@June7 can you try to open the print dialog window via SendKeys "^p", simulating Ctrl+P? to me it would be ok too by doing this way. I need to make it easy for the user to do the print  with one button, in this case, F1 key.

I'll try to do SendKeys "^p" using different from F1 key. Because when I do that, it opens Microsoft webpage.

Do you want direct to printer or do you want to open print dialog? Want to offer users a keyboard activation for print and not just mouse click?

@June7 I would like to direct to printer by pressing one unique key. but due to difficulties, I would accept to open the dialog window via SendKeys "^p" and also confirm Ok via the same way.
